# Using useSelector hooks with context api on top level for perfomance

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Is it worth to define all needed reducer entities required by all components in a tree through useSelector hook at top level component and then pass them where they're needed through context api?

As i read before useSelector hook will check reference equality but woudn't consider parent rerender, so if i would define them at top level component and then pass them by context api would it help in terms of perfomance?

So two approaches:

```
Products(){
<ProductsTable />
<ProductsSidebar />
}

ProductsTable(){
const data = useSelector...
const categories = useSelector...
}

ProductsSidebar(){
const anotherData = useSelector...
}
```

VS

```
Products(){
const data = useSelector...
const categories = useSelector...
const anotherData = useSelector...
return (
<Products.Provider value={data, categories, anotherData}>
<ProductsTable />
<ProductsSidebar />
</Products.Provider>
);
}

ProductsTable(){
const {data, categories} = React.useContext(ProductsContext);
}

ProductsSidebar(){
const {anotherData} = React.useContext(ProductsContext);
}
```

It's just a simple example but let's consider for example that Products component have a lot of nested child components.

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd example all your components get re-rendered on every state change (`data`, `categories`, `anotherData`) because when parent component re-rendered, it will create a new instance of object for context:

```js
<Products.Provider value={{data, categories, anotherData}}>
```

There is no need to hoist state to parent component and create additional context in your case, just leave it as option 1. In this case on storage change only corresponding component will change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question: i heard that it's necessary to divide required data from useSelector. For example: const a = useSelector(myApp.a) const b = useSelector(myApp.b)  instead of: const { a, b } = useSelector(myApp), because then it wouldn't check references properly, is it true?

Comment: By default `useSelector()` compares results of selectors with simple strict equalation. In this case something like `useSelector(state => ({ ... }));` will always cause updates. But you can provide equality function as 2nd argument to avoid such problems: `useSelector(state => ({ a: state.a, b: state.b }), shallowEqual)`. I prefer 2nd option =)